# PayPal Express Checkout - Billing information

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

We're trying to have PayPal Express Checkout payment for a shopping cart (for a live website).

Once the Authorization is completed, we are able to retrieve the Shipping information from the Buyer account (we've successfully tested this on sandbox).

However, is there any 'billing information' that we can get through the API? The owner of the website insists there might be cases where the billing and shipping information are different.

Comment: Forgot to mention an important point: We need billing information as a sales tax component is calculated based on that.

Comment: Put a form on your site, and then use AddressVerify to check the address entered. I'm thinking that is the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can download the billing information for the customer profile.  However, you can set up the sales tax to be applied within the 'merchant services' | Shipping and Tax | Tax Calculator.  This is where you put in the tax rates to be applied.

Comment: Cannot for the life of me find this tax calculator in the sandbox site. Love how the search feature links to the non sandboxed site :(

Comment: You can put in the tax information there, but have you seen it actually applied to the order? My testing has shown that Express Checkout ignores this information.

Comment: That's right - the tax calculator only applies to Payments Standard transactions. Express Checkout expects you to supply tax data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal users can have as many addresses they want saved in Paypal.  These addresses can be unconfirmed or verified, and set as a default billing.    When you use the Express checkout, the user is directed to the paypal website and selects which address they want to use, and that is returned.  You can collect and save address information on your side and then use [AddressVerify](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_AddressVerify) to check if the address is one of their verified addresses on their PayPal account. You past the email and address information as a post in "Name Value Pair" format, and then paypal returns information back as to whether the address exists in their records for that email address.

Comment: I've added a new comment to the question.

Yes, the address that the buyer selects is a shipping address. But I think the 'billing' information doesn't make sense when paying through PayPal. Or does it?